# Running Nginx Docker with SSL self signed certificate

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I am trying to run a UI application with Docker using nginx image I am able to access the service on port 80 without any problem but whenever I am trying access it via https on 443 port I am not able to access the applications the site keeps loading and eventually results in not accessible I have updated the nginx.conf file in default.conf to allow access over port 443

Following is my nginx.conf

```
charset utf-8;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/nginx/html;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/nginx/html; 
}
```

I have added the SSL self-signed certificate in the /usr/nginx folder and exposed port 443 via Dockerfile

The following is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

COPY dist /usr/nginx/html
RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/nginx/html/*

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY domain.crt /usr/nginx

EXPOSE 80:443
ENTRYPOINT nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Can anyone please explain me is port 443 not allowing any access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For nginx server to allow SSL encryption you need to provide ssl flag while listening in nginx.conf
and only ssl certificate will not be sufficient, you will need the ssl certificate key and password as well and they must be configured.

```
charset utf-8;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /usr/nginx/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/nginx/ssl.key;
    ssl_password_file /usr/nginx/ssl.pass;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/nginx/html;
}
```

And you need to put the ssl certificate, key and password via volumes or via embedding in docker container. If you are running container over kubernetes cluster, adding them via kubernetes secrets will be better option.

For Dockerfile you can add like

```
FROM nginx

COPY dist /usr/nginx/html
RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/nginx/html/*

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ssl.crt /usr/nginx/
COPY ssl.pass /usr/nginx/
COPY ssl.key /usr/nginx/

EXPOSE 80:443
ENTRYPOINT nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

For further info you can refer the Nginx Docker article https://medium.com/@agusnavce/nginx-server-with-ssl-certificates-with-lets-encrypt-in-docker-670caefc2e31

Comment: In case of SSL certificates created via openssl do we need to provide all three the certificate, key and password as the certificate and key will be generated form the password

Comment: Actually that can be a possible scenario to use only the password but I haven't done anything similar to it before

Comment: @codeViking93: openssl never generates a key from a password; it generates a key from random data and usually _encrypts_ that key using a password. Nothing (including openssl) can ever generate a certificate from a password. However, openssl can put both the key and certificate in one file which nginx can use (specify for `ssl_certificate` and omit `ssl_certificate_key`) and openssl can leave the key unencrypted so you don't need any password file.